# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

Getting error on when addAdd() call from html template.

```
this.personalForm = this.fb.group({
        user: this.fb.group({
            address: this.fb.array([this.addRows()])     
            }),
addRows() {
  return this.fb.group({
    country: ['']});

addAdd() {
  const control:FormArray = this.personalForm.get[`address`] as FormArray;
  control.push(this.addRows());
}
```

Where i am doing wrong

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

html code

```
<button (click)="addAdd()">Add Address</button>
 <div formArrayName="address">
    <div *ngFor="let add of personalForm.controls?.address?.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <label>Country</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control"   formControlName="country" 
  placeholder="Country" />
 </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case **control** might be null, add a check for null and length.

```
const control:FormArray = this.personalForm.get[`address`] as FormArray;
if(control && control.length >0){
  control.push(this.addRows());
}
```

Comment: failed in compilation

Comment: its my bad working ! grate  thanks, and i want to add into arrays but its just replacing with 1 single array every time i click

Answer (score 1):

get is a function, not an object. Also, you must specify full path to your control.

```
const control:FormArray = this.personalForm.get(['user', 'address']) as FormArray;
```

or

```
const control:FormArray = this.personalForm.get('user.address') as FormArray;
```

Comment: This is working ! superb also incrementing FormArray

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Marko ! this is working, cool !

```
addAdd() {
    const control:FormArray = this.personalForm.get('user.address') as FormArray;  
    control.push(this.addRows());  
  }
```